# Visual Studio Live Server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, web-development-server

I use visual studio code for web development.  when I use live server for open (.js) file the live server open in browser and I saw listing directory/ in my browser
. my .html file work but .Js file cannot work

Comment: If you are  talking about vs code , then right click on .html file and then select open with live server

Comment: Bro I said .html file work but .js file do not work

Comment: Without seeing your code snippets  cant say what is the problem, check if you are correctly loading the scripts

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I saw my problem.Java Script file always attaches to the HTML file and is then show to the browser side. Otherwise in the JS file, when I code to the server-side, first use server code; and then attach HTML file and fs file to show to the terminal